# The ternary operator in Java Linked list Search method

Tags: java, linked-list, conditional-operator

i got a `Syntax error on token "=", != expected` in `temp = temp.next`

Here's the rest of the code

```
static boolean search(int xData) {

    Node temp = head; 

    while (temp != null) {
        return (temp.data == xData ) ? true : temp = temp.next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write something that can't be done with the *conditional* operator.

Instead:

```
if (temp.data == xData) return true;
temp = temp.next;
```

---

```
return (temp.data == xData )? true : temp = temp.next ;
```

Will *always* return. It is a return statement, after all. So, your loop would only ever iterate once.

You could have parenthesized the assignment:

```
return (temp.data == xData )? true : (temp = temp.next);
```

However:

- You're reassigning a local variable immediately before returning - what's the point?
- The type of the expression isn't Boolean, so it's not compatible with the return type of the method.

---

A nicer way to write this would be using a for loop:

```
for (Node temp = head; temp != null; temp = temp.next) {
  if (temp.data == xData) return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't express that logic with the ternary conditional operator, since the 2nd and 3rd operands have different types (`boolean` vs. `Node`).

Besides, you seem to want to break out of the loop (with a return statement) when the condition is true, and stay in the loop otherwise, so the conditional expression makes no sense.

```
static boolean search(int xData) {

    Node temp = head ; 

    while(temp != null) {
       if (temp.data == xData)
           return true;
       temp = temp.next;
    }

    return false ;
}
```